# Ruby SSLServer run https server

Tags: ruby, sockets, https, openssl

I have a custom HTTP server with ruby/socket (just for experimental purposes, no actual use case) and want to try to use SSL/https for the connections. I have tried several solutions with OpenSSL/SSLServer but none of them work.

```
$HOST = "0.0.0.0"
$PORT = 7777
    tcp_server = TCPServer.new($HOST, $PORT)
    ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
    ctx.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new 2048
    ctx.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new
    ctx.cert.subject = OpenSSL::X509::Name.new [["CN", "localhost"]]
    ctx.cert.issuer = ctx.cert.subject
    ctx.cert.public_key = ctx.key
    ctx.cert.not_before = Time.now
    ctx.cert.not_after = Time.now + 60 * 60 * 24
    ctx.cert.sign ctx.key, OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new

    server = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLServer.new tcp_server, ctx
    puts "Server listening on #{$HOST}:#{$PORT.to_s}"
    loop do
        serverThread = Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
            client.print "HTTP/1.1 200\r\n"
            client.print "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
            client.print "\r\n"
            client.print "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
        end
    end
```

That code just causes chrome to say connection not private - NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID

Comment: I forgot to mention, the server runs fine when using tcp_server as server

Comment: For me it looks like it works as expected - only my expectations are different :). You create a certificate which is not trusted by the browser. The browser of course complains about this. Apart from that the certificate does not contain Subject Alternative Names, which makes it invalid for use with Chrome.

Comment: Ok, how would I go about making something that then either generates a trusted certificate or loads a certificate from a file that I already have?

Comment: You cannot generate a trusted certificate unless you have a trusted CA. As for loading certificate from file - see OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new and OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new.

Comment: Oh, ok. I already have a certificate, so I'll try that.